# Division not outputting correct value (PHP)

Tags: php, division

I'm having an issue with the calculated output. I'm simply trying to divide numbers, but it's not coming out correctly.

Let's say $some_value = 1160.00, and $another_value = 1360.

```
<?php
$money_earned = $some_value;
$cost_proposed = $another_value;                               
$money_percentage = (($money_earned / $cost_proposed) * 100);
?>
```

The returned value is: 0.073529411764706

But the actual value should be: 85.29411764705882

Why is this giving me the incorrect output value?

**EDIT:** Here's my true code:

```
$money_earned = calculate_cost($_GET['track']);
$cost_proposed = $res[0]['cost_proposed'];
$money_percentage = (($money_earned / $cost_proposed) * 100);
```

Comment: It worked for me : http://codepad.viper-7.com/tQdHTP

Comment: Can't reproduce. Please post a (non)working code snippet at http://codepad.org that shows this problem.

Comment: Show more of your code, since it works fine for everyone else.

Comment: The code you've pasted gives the result as you expected. Check for the parenthesis for precedence.

Comment: `$money_earned = calculate_cost($_GET['track']);
$cost_proposed = $res[0]['cost_proposed'];                               
$money_percentage = (($money_earned / $cost_proposed) * 100);`

That's what my true code is.  It definitely works if plugging the numbers in as the values.  But when pulling from the DB, the same exact values, it seems to error.

Comment: `var_dump` all the involved values before the calculation. Math doesn't screw up in PHP based on where the values come from, you're very likely simply not working with the values you think you are.

Comment: my $money_earned var_dump gives me: string(8) "1,160.00"

Comment: That's your problem. It's a string not an integer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an error in your maths somewhere.

0.073529411764706 * 1360 = 100

Therefore what you actually have in code is:

```
$money_percentage = 100 / $cost_proposed
```

Double check your code to see where you're getting that equation from.

Edit: based on comments, you're converting a string with a comma in it into an integer. This breaks at the comma, so you end with 1. Fits the maths perfectly.

Strip the commas and convert to integer to get it to work. Ideally, store all numbers as numbers, only add the commas when you display on screen.

```
$number = (int)str_replace("," , "", $string);
```

Comment: In other words, this is the answer you'd get if `$some_value = 1`.